# Systemd config for later mounted encrypted volume with services working on it

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, raspberry-pi, luks, dm-crypt

**Hi everyone**, 
I am working on a Banana Pi with Arch Linux and
i am currently trying to accomplish the following:

1. After someone mounted the encrypted keyfiles for my external storage systemd shall use them and mount the external storage
2. systemd shall start all services that operate on the external storage
3. On shutdown everything shall be stopped before unmounting the encrypted volume

---

After some hours it finally worked and I wonder if there is a smaller solution:

### /etc/systemd/system

### luks.keys.path

```
[Unit]
Description=luks-keys found in /etc/luks-keys

[Path]
DirectoryNotEmpty=/etc/luks-keys/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### luks.keys.service

```
[Unit]
Description=luks-keys availible
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/storage
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

### storage.target

```
[Unit]
Description=Storage
Requires=basic.target
After=multi-user.target
Requisite=luks.keys.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

### ./storage.target.wants/minidlna.service

```
[Unit]
Description=minidlna server
After=network.target
Requisite=luks.keys.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/minidlnad -P /run/minidlna/minidlna.pid
PIDFile=/run/minidlna/minidlna.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=storage.target
```

### /usr/local/bin/storage

```
#!/bin/bash

systemclt isolate storage.target

cryptsetup --key-file /etc/luks-keys/storage1 luksOpen /dev/sda1 storage1

mount /dev/mapper/storage1 /mnt/storage1
```

---

### Pi boots:

- systemd starts multi-user.target
- activates luks.keys.path witch waits for files in /etc/luks-keys
- files found
- luks.keys.service is activated and starts storage.target
- the other services are starting

### Before unmount:

- systemctl trys to stop luks.keys.service
- storage.target and the other services are stopping because then need luks.keys.service
- luks.keys.service finally stops and the shutdown continuous with
  umount.target

---

If its not possible to accomplish this with less work i am happy to present the Answer to the question:

> **How to configure systemd for a later mounted encrypted volume with
>   services working on it**

Comment: You can create an on demand unit file in systemd for a later mounted encrypted volume.So as soon as it finds a mounted encrypted volume your luks.keys.path should get the keys and rest of the operations are same as  you mentioned above.

Comment: You mean i can remove the path file and modify the luks.keys.service into a on demand unit so it starts automatically when the keyfile volume will appear? ... But what do you mean with a on-demand unit? I can only find systemd.mount in the man page ...
By the way: I just realized that nothing is checking if the encrypted storage volume itself is available at all.